# How to make BIND behave differently depending on query source?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, query, source

How would one make BIND behave differently depending on the source IP address? For example, I want to use different forwarding DNS servers for different people on my network.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Set up "views" in Bind](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.9/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2590750). The Internet has a very large number of tutorials on this; pick your favorite and run with it.